# What do we mean by convergence of a series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

While learning calculus I stumbled upon this concept of convergence. Is this some general concept or just related to sequence and series. What is its importance?

Comment: Have you read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_series)?

Comment: The big motivation behind it is it allows us to assign some value to an infinite object in a way that makes sense.  $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$ doesn't necessarily need to equal any finite number (something like $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k$ doesn't.), but it (the first sum) does, namely $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: @Mark can you please convert your comment to answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it is a more general concept. In calculus you see it in the context of sequences and series. Later on it is developed more abstractly. In real analysis, for instance, the notion of convergence is crucial in the definition of continuity. Even more general is its treatment in topology where closed sets can be defined as those who contained the limits of sequences in them.

Answer (score 0):

Convergernce in general is an important concept in calculus, I just want to give you an idea what it´s about.

Given an set with a distance function that measures the distance of two elements with positiv real numbers.
$(S,d(.,.))$
Convergence of a sequence $s_n$ to an element $x_0$ (series are special sequences) is always defined as such:
$\forall\epsilon>0\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}\forall n>n_0:d(x_0,s_n)<\epsilon$
This expresses that at some point the series will be contained in an arbitrary small neighbourhood of $x_0$ and never leaf. There are also Chauchy sequences, who don´t need a point to converge to; This is necessary for $\mathbb{Q}$ where a series can converge to a irrational number.

If you want examples of more abstract distance you might look into Hausdorf  dimension. On subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ the distance of $A,B$ can be defined as the smallest distance $\delta$ such that every point of $A$ has some point in $B$ such that the distance of those two points is smaller than $\delta$.

With this definition the cantor series will converge to the cantor set:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set